# I can't get images to display in my C based proxy

Tags: c++, c, sockets, proxy, network-programming

So I'm trying to create a C based proxy system and I'm having trouble reading the image data that goes through the connection. I can visit pages normally for the most part but when I try sending the image data back to the browser from the server I can't see the image. Below is the code used to receive the data from the server and then send the message to the browser. I hope someone will have a clue to help me, thanks! *The proxy blocks odd byte content from showing, that's part of the code there, but the image I'm trying to load is even # of bytes.

```
    do {

                    //Receive message from server
                    bytes = recv(clientsockfd, messagein, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, 0);

                    if(bytes > 0)
                        strncpy(messageout,messagein,bytes);

                    else if(bytes == 0) {
                        printf("\nConnection closed\n");
                        strcpy(messageout,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
                    }

                    printf("Answer received from server: \n");
                    printf("%s\n\nTotal Bytes: %d\n\n", messagein, bytes);

                    //Copy the messagein to a tempStr so we can leave original message untouched
                    strncpy(tempStr,messagein,bytes);

                    //Check to see if the content is even or odd only if the message in has a content length field, later we will determine if we do anything with it
                    if(strstr(messagein,"Content-Length:") != NULL)
                        evenContent = checkContent(tempStr);

                    //If the content is odd then we want to change the message we'll send back to the browser
                    if(!evenContent) {
                        //If the page is odd then I redirect the user to carey's error page he made
                        if(strstr(messagein,"text/html") != NULL)
                            strcpy(messageout,"HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nLocation: http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~carey/CPSC441/errorpage.html\r\n\r\n");
                        else if(strstr(messagein,"image/") != NULL) {
                            //If the image is odd then I just send back empty data to the browser
                            strcpy(messageout,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
                        }
                    }
#ifdef DEBUG
                    printf("\n\nAbout to send message to the web browser:\n%s",messageout);
#endif
                    /* send the result message back to the browser */
                    send(childsockfd, messageout, bytes, 0);

                    /* initialize message strings just to be safe (null-terminated) */
                    for( i = 0; i < MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH; i++ )
                    {
                        messagein[i] = '\0';
                        messageout[i] = '\0';
                        tempStr[i] = '\0';
                    }

                } while (bytes != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You suppose here that the header and the content are obtained together by a single call to `recv`. But for large request that may not be true (and images are usually large). To do the parsing right you should call `recv` until you had parsed header including content-length and then call `recv` until you have received content-length amount of bytes.

Comment: But when I call 'recv' doesn't it eventually just sit there waiting for a message? So won't my program hang? What I thought to do was check to see if Content-Length: existed in the message so then I'd know if it's header or data, then continue with the code, the image I'm checking now returns a total of 3027 bytes with the header included so it fits in the buffer, my main concern now is why even that isn't working

Comment: `recv` will return as soon as some message will arrive (note that it will not necessarily will be the whole message). If you care about hanging you can set timeout on the socket by using `setsockopt` with `SO_RCVTIMEO` flag.

Comment: Hmmm I tried what you said, now I have the loop to keep asking for `recv` and it turns out that there was an auto timeout value sent, I moved a bit further, but looks like the server sends part of the data and then doesn't want to send anymore, do I need to ask for the data again after `recv`?

Comment: C-style string functions:(    Is the image data encoded, (eg. base64),  and, if so, how?

Comment: Don't think so, it's just a basic html page, our prof just added a basic jpeg I'm pretty sure, server doesn't say anything about encoding

Comment: If it can contain nulls, zero bytes, you're stuft.